# Extend dryer termination away from condensing unit

Tags: air-conditioning, dryer, exhaust-vent

How can I extend my dryer's exhaust vent away from my A.C. condensing unit using the existing outlet?

It currently looks like the picture below. I don't know if the vent going through the wall is connected with the cover on the outside or not.

[image: Dryer exhaust vent next to A.C. condensing unit]

Comment: You really don't want the vent anywhere close to the unit. the lint that escapes will be sucked in to the condenser coils and reduce the efficiency. Would it be possible to go under the house and come up and out in a different location? Further away would be worth the cost and trouble because of the damage the lint can cause. Plus you will be sucking warm air when the dryer is running causing the system to work harder but this is way less of a concern than the lint.

Comment: @EdBeal Thank you for your notes. That is very good advice regarding the risks with the condenser coils. I don't want to extend this project to re-routing the exhaust vent into another room (which is what would have to happen). I could go under the house and come up and out, but that would be quite a bit of work and probably beyond my skill level.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the vent cover, attach some rigid duct work, run along the house a few feet, put the vent cover on the end of the run. Make sure the end of the new run is lower than the exit point, so that moisture/condensation will never run inside.

BTW, make sure the ductwork inside is rigid. If it isn't replace that too.

Comment: That's a good point about making sure that the end of the new run is lower than the exit. How far should the run go from the condensing unit? What is the best way to attach the cover and various pieces of the rigid duct work?